# jQuery.toggle() not working on a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

On a web page we have a list of profiles. On the right hand side of the profile is some text, followed by an arrow `img#arrow`.

When `img#arrow` is clicked, we have the following jQuery we hope to run:

However, the corresponding `.bottom-sec` is not toggling.

```js
jQuery('#arrow').click(function(){
    var $parent = $(this).parent();
    $($parent).addClass('active');
    jQuery($parent +' .bottom-sec').toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="profile-right">
    <h2>Bob Brown</h2> 
    <h3>Non-Executive Chairman</h3> 
    <p>Intially showing text.</p>
    <div class="bottom-sec" style="display: none;">
        <p>Initially hidden text.</p>
    </div>
    <img id="arrow" src="/wp-content/themes/wtc/images/icons/down-arrow-circle-hi.png"> 
</div>
```

Comment: `this` + [Traversing](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/traversing/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem**

The problem with your code is exactly what the comment on your question is saying, but he didn't explain anything:

You're combining two different ways of selecting elements. One is with selectors, the other is traversing. You're using them in a way which isn't possible (the `$parent + ' .bottom-sec'` part). The comment linked to a [jQuery page about traversing](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/traversing/) which you should definitely read! It tells you a lot about how to use traversing functions, which you could use!

**Solution**

There are multiple solutions to this, but I'll write down the one I think is the best:

First of all, change the HTML a bit. I've removed the element style of `.bottom-sec` and changed the id of the image to a class, because you have multiple images with the same id on the page, which is not a recommended thing to do. Classes can occur more than once, id's cannot.

```
<div class="profile-right">
    <h2>Bob Brown</h2> 
    <h3>Non-Executive Chairman</h3> 
    <p>Intially showing text.</p>
    <div class="bottom-sec">
        <p>Initially hidden text.</p>
    </div>
    <img class="arrow" src="/wp-content/themes/wtc/images/icons/down-arrow-circle-hi.png"> 
</div>
```

I've reduced the JavaScript to the following. Note that is just reduced to one line, where a click on the `.arrow` element goes searching for the closest `.profile-right` parent. If, for whatever reason, you decide to change the HTML and the `.arrow` element is no longer a child of the `.profile-right`, this code still works. The only thing it does is toggle an `active` class on the `.profile-right`.

```
jQuery(document).on('ready', function() {
    jQuery('.arrow').on('click', function(){
        jQuery(this).closest('.profile-right').toggleClass('active');
    });
});
```

The document ready listener was added because of OP's comment.

With CSS, we can use the new `.active` class to show or hide the element.

```
.profile-right .bottom-sec {
    display: none
}

.profile-right.active .bottom-sec {
    display: block
}
```

**Original Code Fix**

If for some reason you wanted to use your original code, this is how it should be:

```
// Nothing wrong about this part. 
// Your only worry should be that there could be 
// multiple elements with the same ID, which is something really bad.
jQuery('#arrow').click(function(){
    // This part is correct, no worries
    var $parent = $(this).parent();
    // Removed the $(...), because $parent is already a jQuery object
    $parent.addClass('active');
    // Changed the selector to a find function
    $parent.find('.bottom-sec').toggle();
});
```

You could also combine all of the code inside the listener function to just one line:

```
jQuery('#arrow').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().addClass('active').find('.bottom-sec').toggle();
});
```

Comment: Thank you Douwe. That worked for an individual .arrow / .bottom-sec, but not when there were multiple copies of profiles. Can you please look at [this page](http://batmin.insightcomdes.com.au/about-us/leadership/board/), you'll see the jQuery at line 234, but the down arrows are not working. Help appreciated.

Comment: You load that part of the JavaScript before the elements are displayed / loaded. I'll update my code in a second, with a document ready wrapper around the code!

Comment: Thanks Douwe. I've wrapped the code in a document ready, but the click on the `.arrow` doesn't seem to be adding the `.active` class to the `.profile-right`.

Comment: Hi Douwe, perhaps try clearing your browser cache? I see `jQuery(document).on('ready', function() {
    jQuery('.arrow').on('click', function(){
        jQuery(this).closest('.profile-right').toggleClass('active');
    });
});`

Comment: @Steve I see the problem: You've added the code multiple times, like for each `.profile-right`. Can you move the code to a JavaScript file or the bottom of the page? Or could you edit the JavaScript on line 234 in the source code of the file?

Answer (score 0):

Change your js code like below.

```
jQuery('#arrow').click(function(){
    var $parent = $(this).parent();
    $($parent).addClass('active');
    jQuery($parent).find('.bottom-sec').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

In your event listener you can catch the element (the down arrow) that triggered the event. It will be referred as `this`.

Then you can go through the DOM tree using [`.next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) and [`.parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) to access the `<div>` to toggle.

---

Note: you may need more functions than the one I explained above.

Note 2: without code or more detailed information, we can't help you further, I will edit this answer if you add details.